# Finding all zeros of $f(z)=\sin(\frac{z}{\pi})$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to find the zeros of the function $f(z)=\sin(\frac{z}{\pi})$.

I began by noting that we can define $g(z)=\sin(z)$ as $g(z)=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{iz}-e^{-iz}\right)$, so:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{i\frac{z}{\pi}}-e^{-i\frac{z}{\pi}}\right)$$

Now we need to find all values of $z$ that satisfy:

$$e^{i\frac{z}{\pi}}=e^{-i\frac{z}{\pi}} \Leftrightarrow e^{2i\frac{z}{\pi}}=1$$

This is only true if $2\frac{z}{\pi}=2k\pi$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. So we end up with $z=k\pi^2$. But my complex analysis textbook says that the zeros of that funcion are all $z\in \mathbb{Z}$. So my question is: Is the textbook wrong? Or am I making some kind of obvious mistake that I did no notice?

Comment: all $z\in\mathbb Z$ are zeroes of $f(z)=\sin(z\pi)$

Comment: There are typos in textbooks. This is clearly one of them. Should probably be $\sin(z \pi)$ and not $\sin(z/\pi)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle \sin{\frac z{\pi}} = 0 = \sin(k\pi)$

$\displaystyle \frac z{\pi} = k\pi$

$\displaystyle z = k\pi^2$

Your textbook answer is wrong for the problem you've given. If the problem had been to find the zeroes of $\displaystyle \sin(z\pi)$, that would've been correct.